# Problem maintaing order with geom_tile and duplicated data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to don't loose the order of dataframe, the information has order in the dataframe.
But since the data is duplicated into the dataframe, I am obtaining error message or introducing NA.
I didnt find a solution similar for this, I tried with this [How to preserve the order of tiles in geom_tile ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429993/how-to-preserve-the-order-of-tiles-in-geom-tile-ggplot), but it didn't work

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

url_soccer <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frm1789/soccer_ea/master/tableau.m.csv'

tableau.m <- read_csv(url_soccer)

tableau.m <- tableau.m[,-1]

(p <- ggplot(tableau.m, aes(Team, variable)) + 
geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") + 
scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue"))
```

The expected solution is this:
[image: How the visualization should be...]

Comment: In the others cases (at least as far as I looked for) they didn't find repetitive elements in the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder your variables, see:

```
tableau.m$Team <- factor(tableau.m$Team, c("Brasil", "Argentina", "Uruguay"))
tableau.m$variable <- factor(tableau.m$variable, c("Titles", "Match", "Points", "Points_1", "Performance"))

ggplot(tableau.m, aes(variable, Team, fill = rescale)) + 
  geom_tile(show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]